# Como colocar uma variável char em uma string através das chaves { }?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Estou fazendo um jogo da velha, onde existe uma função que imprime ela, e outra que contem as 9 posições jogáveis, eu simplifiquei o código para não ficar muito grande e coloquei apenas uma posição.

Existe a possibilidade de fazer igual ao *console.writeline*, onde colocamos o índice e ao final da string colocamos a variável?

```
private static char[] posJogaveis = { '_' };
public static string[] updateVelha()
{
string[] structVelha = { " _{0}_", posJogaveis[0].ToString() };
return structVelha;
}
private static string[] structVelha = updateVelha();
```

A ideia era alterar as posições, mas esse método não existe ou estou fazendo da maneira errada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando `String.Format` assim:

```
String.Format("{0}", posJogaveis[0].ToString());
```

Se você puder utilizar a versão C# 6.0 ou superior, você tem a opção de usar interpolação de string. Usando interpolação você apenas poe um `$` na frente das aspas, e quando precisar mostrar uma variável, abra brackets e use a variável fechando logo em seguida.  Exemplo:

```
$"_{ posJogaveis[0] }_";
```

No caso de mais de uma posição:

```
$"_{ posJogaveis[0] }_|_{ posJogaveis[1] }_|_{ posJogaveis[2] }_";
```

Mais informações sobre [interpolação de strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Então no final não preciso dizer qual variável é, apenas colocar ela na string exatamente como você fez?

Comment: Sim, por interpolação você não faz nada no final, você realmente vai botando as variáveis onde elas deviam estar como botei de exemplo. E não precisa do ToString, é redundante.

Comment: Só um lembrete que a interpolação de strings está disponível apenas do C# 6 em diante.

Comment: Realmente, esqueci do detalhe da versão e também não foi específicado pelo autor, mas vou por um adendo de qualquer forma.